# websocket handshake fails with c# server

Tags: c#, hash, encoding, websocket

I tried to set up a server side Websocket in C# as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers but as soon as I try to connect it fails with `Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept'`

```
        public string ComputeWebSocketHandshakeSecurityHash(String secWebSocketKey) {
        const String MagicKEY = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        String secWebSocketAccept = String.Empty;

        // 1. Combine the request Sec-WebSocket-Key with magic key.
        String ret = secWebSocketKey + MagicKEY;

        // 2. Compute the SHA1 hash
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] sha1Hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ret));

        // 3. Base64 encode the hash
        secWebSocketAccept = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Hash);
        return secWebSocketAccept 
        };
```

The example an the page points out that `dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==`should result in `s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=` and that is working.

Here are the example headers from Chrome client:

Request Headers:

```
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
        Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
        Cache-Control: no-cache
        Connection: Upgrade
        Host: localhost:4444
        Origin: https://localhost
        Pragma: no-cache
        Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
        Sec-WebSocket-Key: GW/l6VLlmjmmwZ2U6BMg7g==
        Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: plain
        Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
        Upgrade: websocket
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)             AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
        Connection: Upgrade
        Sec-WebSocket-Accept: RNBWSHjxgtG6/yEZKh/9U776A5U=
        Upgrade: WebSocket
```

Its obvious that the accept key seems not match the request key but why?
And why it is working for the mozilla ws example that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. But as it points out, it had nothing to do with the code above; this is working as intended. The reason why this always failed to connect was a wrong key that has been passed to the function causing a wrong result. (I will keep the post so others can use the code to create hashes).

In my test I tried to pass data to the function using

```
sData = sReader.ReadLine();
        if (sData.StartsWith("Sec-WebSocket-Key: "))
        {
            string key = sData.Substring(19, sData.Length - 19).Trim(' ');
            String hashKey = ComputeSocketAcceptString(key);
            //Response here
        }
```

However the substring that was extracted the code from the request was not correct. That caused the function to compute a wrong hash.

For all that are searching some correct request/response values to test with, here are some:

`Sec-WebSocket-Key: fAB2VSri/zcQdblwjKH9Ow==
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: sGQcFOVDy7ctcd9TTk4Jr9vtXaQ=`

`Sec-WebSocket-Key: +YFXjHbEdHlvigafwh/Ixw==
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: xdj5tRanzBYNvV31W6QIY5+mNjI=`

`Sec-WebSocket-Key: bNS0upBX5U6lICKLvFokUg==
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: G66BkTwtxFeWMHaV7Dm/Cd4g+Rg=`